# C++ Constructor expecting a ":" (colon)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I'm loosing my nerves over the following code, but before we start you need to know I'm kinda' new to C++

```
#include <CPUID.h>

namespace CPU {

  class CPUGeneric {
    protected:
      CPUID* _cpuid;
    public
      CPUGeneric(CPUID* cpuid) : _cpuid(cpuid) {};
  };

  class CPUIntel : CPUGeneric {
    public:
      CPUIntel(CPUID* cpuid) : CPUGeneric(cpuid) {};
  };

}

void main(...) { 
  CPUID* cpuid = new CPUID();
  CPUIntel* cpu = new CPUIntel(cpuid);
}
```

The problem with the code above (according to the IDE) is the CPUGeneric constructor. It has the red underline and it says: expected a ':'

I can't figure out what other chaining it requires.

Comment: Often syntax errors are reported on the line after they occur. `public` is missing a colon.

Comment: Often they are reported in completely different files altogether, when templates are involved. Welcome to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! 
If the linked code is carbon-copy of your code, then your problem might be the missing colon after "public" at line #8

Comment: you're right. OMG... i need to sleep more. thanks a lot!